# Rendering multiple spirtes from an array in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, sprite, render

I have no idea why this for loop is only showing the last sprite in my array. I'm somewhat new to AS3 and wondering why it is doing this:

```
private function loadComplete(event:Event):void {

var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);

for (var i:int = 0; i <  4; i++ ) {
   var pB:BitmapData = new BitmapData(image.width / 2, image.height / 2, false, 0x000000FF);
    pB.copyPixels(image.bitmapData, new Rectangle(i * 20 , i * 20, image.width / 2, image.height / 2), new Point(0, 0));
    pieces.push(new Piece(new Sprite(), 0, 0));
    pieces[i].getSprite().graphics.beginBitmapFill(new Bitmap(pB.clone()).bitmapData, null, false);
    pieces[i].getSprite().graphics.drawRect(0, 0, image.width / 2, image.height / 2);
    pieces[i].getSprite().graphics.endFill();
    pieces[i].getSprite().addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downHandler);
    pieces[i].getSprite().addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragPiece);

    addChild(pieces[i].getSprite());

       }
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upHandler);
    }
```

Piece Class:

```
public class Piece 
{
    private var pieceX:int;
    private var pieceY:int;
    private var sprite:Sprite;

    public function Piece(sprite:Sprite, pieceX:int, pieceY:int):void 
    {
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.pieceX = pieceX;
        this.pieceY = pieceY;
    }

    public function getSprite():Sprite {
        return sprite;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited your post to fix your code formatting and for clarity of your question.

Comment: Are they all layered on top of each other ? I can't really tell as I cannot see the `Piece` class and what it might do.

Comment: The Piece class only holds a Sprite and an X and Y position.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can make your `Piece` class `extends Sprite`, and use Sprite's functional without that ugly `getSprite()` construction, just over a piece.

```
public class Piece extends Sprite {
    private var pieceX:int=0;
    private var pieceY:int=0;
    public function Piece(pieceX:int=0,pieceY:int=0) {
        this.pieceX = pieceX;
        this.pieceY = pieceY;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in order to see more than a single piece, you have to alter sprite's X and Y properties, otherwise they are indeed stacked one over another.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i <  4; i++ ) {
    var pB:BitmapData = new BitmapData(image.width / 2, image.height / 2, false, 0x000000FF);
    pB.copyPixels(image.bitmapData, new Rectangle(i * 20 , i * 20, image.width / 2, image.height / 2), new Point(0, 0));
    var piece:Piece=new Piece(0,0);
    pieces.push(piece);
    piece.graphics.beginBitmapFill(pB.clone(), null, false);
    piece.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, image.width / 2, image.height / 2);
    piece.graphics.endFill();
    piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downHandler);
    piece.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragPiece);

    addChild(piece);
    // here, add "piece.x=" and "piece.y=" assignments with correct values. For example
    piece.x=Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth-piece.width);
    piece.y=math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-piece.height);

}
```

Also why cloning that bitmap via creating a Bitmap object? `pB.clone()` works without any problems. (Tried just `pB` and discovered that `beginBitmapFill()` maintains bitmap link, thus changes the image if the base bitmap changes.)

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't let me answer this yesterday but you were right. I just had to change the x value. Thank you!